# Output html element content in another innerHTML js

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, fetch-api

I want to create a dynamic URL. The domain part should remain the same. For example: In this URL "https://www.google.com/search?", I want to append content fetched from another website.

I use this js to fetch and store result to Html element "KK1"

```
<script>
'use strict';

(async () => {
let response = await fetch('https://api.com/values/1');

let text = await response.text(); // read response body as text

document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = (text.slice(0, 80) );

})()
</script>
```

Assuming the response received from fetch is **amoeba1**, I want to generate a URL like *"https://www.google.com/search?amoeba1"*

**My code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>
'use strict';

(async () => {
let response = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP');

let text = await response.text(); // read response body as text

document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = (text.slice(0, 80) );

})()
</script>
<title>My title Dowmloder.rar</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

Generate clickable URL from parameters.

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "https://www.google.com/search?"+ "I ADD WHAT HERE TO??"; 
</script>

BELOW IS THE STRING I WANT TO APPEND.
<p id="KK1"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

How do I append the fetched string? The string is already in 
`<p id="KK1"></p>`

Looking Forward to getting help.

Comment: What is #KK1 an anchor tag/div/p?

Comment: its a <p id="KK1"></p>

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing by generating that string. Setting `innerHTML` of a `<p>` as you have should do it. Do u want to generate an actual clickable link there? (May be an `anchor` link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for anchor tag & you want to add dynamic `href`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>
'use strict';
var res = "";
(async () => {
let response = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP');

let text = await response.text(); // read response body as text

document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = (text.slice(0, 80) );

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "https://www.google.com/search?"+  text;
document.getElementById("demo").href = "https://www.google.com/search?"+  encodeURI(text);
})()
</script>
<title>My title Dowmloder.rar</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

Generate clickable URL from parameters.

<a id="demo"></a><br>


BELOW IS THE STRING I WANT TO APPEND.
<p id="KK1"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect code. Exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot @Ritesh Khandekar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify your script to store in a variable the text result from your API call then with template literals, using `${}` you can build your new string for `demo` element.

Like the following

```
const resultText = text.slice(0, 80);
document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = resultText;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `https://www.google.com/search?${resultText}`;
```

Or there are other ways to concatenate a string like:

`'https://www.google.com/search?' + resultText`

Read further here: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Update:**

So you need to merge those two `<script>` tags what you have.

I guess this will do that job for you:

```
'use strict';

(async () => {
   let response = await fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP');

   let text = await response.text(); // read response body as text

   // essential modified part:
   const resultText = text.slice(0, 80);
   document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = resultText;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `https://www.google.com/search?${resultText}`;
})();
```

And don't forget to remove this one:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "https://www.google.com/search?"+ "I ADD WHAT HERE TO??"; 
</script>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @norbitrial. I've not succeeded. Maybe you can look at the whole code and advice.

Comment: @gilbaO Just updated my answer, I hope that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "https://www.google.com/search?" + document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML

Comment: Thanks @madhu. I've tried this but it's not working.

Comment: Try innerText instead of innerHTML